# Select all lines starting with a character and keep only one entry

Tags: regex

I'm using a firefox addon called "rikaisama", this addon is a pop up dictionary for japanese and it allows epwing dictionary files. In the addon option we can use one regular expression to remove unnecessary parts of a dictionary entry.

I'm using the "Kenkyusha's New Japanese-English Dictionary" epwing file but it has way too much examples to be readable.

Example of an entry :

```
まにあう【間に合う】 ﾛｰﾏ(maniau)
1 〔時間に遅れない〕 be in time 《for…》.
▲7 時の列車に間に合う　catch [make] the 7 o'clock train
・締め切りに間に合う　meet the deadline
・開演に間に合う　arrive before curtain time
▲9 時の札幌行きに間に合うように空港に着いた.　I arrived in time for the nine o'clock flight to Sapporo.
・「間に合うかな」「走っても間に合いそうにないね」　"Will we be in time?"―"It doesn't look like we'll be in time even if we run."
2 〔役に立つ〕 answer [serve, suit, meet] the purpose; be useful; be serviceable; be of ￼use [service]; be good enough; 〔十分である〕 be enough; 〔用意ができる〕 be ready; 〔必要をみたす〕 meet the requirements; serve ￼the [one's] turn [need].
▲「費用はどのぐらいかな」「5 万もあれば間に合うよ」　"And what is the expense?"―"Fifty-thousand yen should cover it."
・これだけあれば丸 1 年は間に合う.　This will ￼last us [see us through] one whole year. ｜ This will be enough for a whole year.
```

Where all entries starting with "▲" or "・" are examples and all entries matching this regex are definitions :

```
\n[″*〖〈《⇒＝➡【〔(〜A-Za-z0-9].*
```

I already managed to come up with this regular expression on my own but it removes all examples:

```
\n[^″*〖〈《⇒＝➡【〔(〜A-Za-z0-9].*
```

Is it possible to have a regex matching this regex AND the following line of the match ?

Wished result :

```
まにあう【間に合う】 ﾛｰﾏ(maniau)
1 〔時間に遅れない〕 be in time 《for…》.
▲7 時の列車に間に合う　catch [make] the 7 o'clock train
2 〔役に立つ〕 answer [serve, suit, meet] the purpose; be useful; be serviceable; be of ￼use [service]; be good enough; 〔十分である〕 be enough; 〔用意ができる〕 be ready; 〔必要をみたす〕 meet the requirements; serve ￼the [one's] turn [need].
▲「費用はどのぐらいかな」「5 万もあれば間に合うよ」　"And what is the expense?"―"Fifty-thousand yen should cover it."
```

Any help appreciated !

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO. If I understand correctly you are looking to grab certain lines from your files - what I don't fully understand is the conditions you are wanting to match by. That is, when is a line accepted and when should it be ignored?

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome !

I would like to keep every line matching this regex : \n[″*〖〈《⇒＝➡【〔(〜A-Za-z0-9].*
and keep the first following line while deleting everything else.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Like I said, I'm using an addon called "rikaisama" which has a feature built in to input a single regular expression for deletion of ext.
Feature in question : https://i.imgur.com/2c87e4T.png

Comment: If you can specify the replacement and multiline mode, you may use https://regex101.com/r/J8yBwP/1

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to specify the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it I think - just add `\n.*` so it becomes `/\n[″*〖〈《⇒＝➡【〔(〜A-Za-z0-9].*\n.*/`. That makes it get the next line...

See it in action here: https://regexr.com/442st

Comment: How would I go about selecting the opposite of the matched regex ? 

It works really well but I need to delete everything that doesn't match what you just send.

Comment: You could just replace the string with the matched result - that would have the same effect.

Comment: I'm really sorry I don't understand what you mean.